# Unity drag doesn't work, object moves away from the pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've attached the following script to an `Image` inside the `Canvas` :

```
public class DragMe : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.transform.localPosition += (Vector3)eventData.delta;
    }
}
```

The problem is, as I drag further, the `Image` goes away more and more from under the pointer. When I drag back to the start position the `Image` comes back where it was under the finger/pointer.

changing the code to:

```
this.transform.position = eventData.position;
```

causes the object to jump away somewhere else.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**
Guys, if you read my code and the supposed duplicate question you see their answer is my question! But it has an issue, i.e. the object doesn't stay under the dragging finger/pointer and keeps going away further as you keep dragging!

**Update 2:**
`Image`:

[image]

Canvas:

[image]

Camera:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473802/unity3d-ui-calculation-for-position-dragging-an-item

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D UI, calculation for position dragging an item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473802/unity3d-ui-calculation-for-position-dragging-an-item)

Comment: @Aybe It is what already I've done and is not working

Comment: @Draco18s It is the same code as in my question, but it has an issue that they haven't noticed I guess.

Comment: Please show the transform properties of the image and also the canvas.

Comment: @shingo Please have a look at the screenshots. as I drag, the object doesn't stay under my finger, like if it has a different scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `Screen Space - Overlay` if the camera's viewport is unchanged. Then following code will work:

```
this.transform.position = eventData.position;
```

To use `Screen Space - Camera`, you need transform the event position into the camera space:

```
Vector3 position = eventData.position;
var canvas = image.canvas;
position.z = canvas.planeDistance;
image.transform.position = canvas.worldCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
```